# How to show results from a join even if where clause removes those results

Tags: sql

I have a query that joins to a Counties table.  That table contains 14 different counties.  I am counting the number of members in each county from a span of time.  When that span of time I choose doesn't include any members from a certain county, the county doesn't show up, no matter if I use a Right join or Inner join to the county table.  My goal is that if no members are returned from a county, to show 0 for that county total.  How would I do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.County,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.MemberID) AS TotalUniqueProviders
FROM
    dw.FactMedicalClaimLine a
INNER JOIN 
    dw.DimMember d
ON
    a.MemberKey = d.MemberKey
RIGHT JOIN
    dw.DimGeography e
ON
    a.GeographyKey = e.GeographyKey
WHERE
    LEFT(ServiceDate, 6) >= 201001
    AND LEFT(PaidDate, 6) BETWEEN 201010 AND 201012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your filter into the `JOIN` clause

```
RIGHT JOIN
    dw.DimGeography e
ON
    a.GeographyKey = e.GeographyKey
AND
    LEFT(ServiceDate, 6) >= 201001
    AND LEFT(PaidDate, 6) BETWEEN 201010 AND 201012
```

The country rows preserved because of the `OUTER JOIN` will have `NULL` for `ServiceDate` and `PaidDate` and so end up getting excluded by your `WHERE` clause.

You also seem to be missing a `GROUP BY e.GeographyKey` in the posted version of your query and you don't need `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks so much Martin!   This worked for me!  And yes, I forgot to copy in my group by clause but I did have it in the original query.  I will remove the distinct as well, didn't realize I put that in there.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `WHERE` with `AND` i.e:

```
ON     a.GeographyKey = e.GeographyKey 
AND    LEFT(ServiceDate, 6) >= 201001     
AND LEFT(PaidDate, 6) BETWEEN 201010 AND 201012
```